# When performing a TIN interpolation on vector data to create a DEM, is there any reason NOT to increase column/row size to create a smoother DEM?

Tags: qgis

For example, when I load my vector data into the TIN interpolation GUI, a column/row size of 300x300 is automatically filled in.  But when using those values, my DEM is very blocky.  Is there any reason why I shouldn't increase to something like 1200x1200, which creates a much smoother DEM?

[image]

Comment: There are two problems that I can think of. First, increasing grid size increases storage and slows down many operations quite a bit (e.g. flow routing, viewshedding, etc.). Secondly, you should not have a grid density that is greater than your source data density as this can lead to various problems. It's best to choose a grid resolution that is reflective of the density of the source data.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly the column/row relationship to the data is?  Is it literally referring to the number of entries in the associated attribute table?  Or is this some measure of resolution, where the number of columns and rows needs to stick to the same ratio?

My point height data has, for example, 50,000 entries.  Just trying to get an idea of how I can get the best reflection of this data in my DEM.

Comment: It is the number of rows and columns in the raster grid of the interpolated DEM. Yes, this will likely be of a similar aspect ratio since that is determined by the extent of the source data. The greater the number of rows and columns the greater the overall number of grid cells in the raster and the higher the storage/memory requirements of the data.

Comment: I've crashed QGIS a few times now in an attempt to use _all_ the entries, but still get pretty good results when inputting less.  How does the algorithm decide which entries to skip when the input column/row values are lower than the total number of values in the attribute table?  Does it cut them off at one point, skip every third, etc?